# PSQL ignores port parameter

Tags: psql

I'm trying to connect to a database which is running on a non-default port using PSQL:

```
PSQL SYNOPSIS
       psql [option...] [dbname [username]]

psql -h wrds-pgdata.wharton.upenn.edu –p 9737 -W myDatabase myAccountName 
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "myDatabase" ignored
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "myAccountName" ignored
Password for user 9737:
```

Notice that the -p command is simply ignored. Somehow psql assumes that 9737 is the username! Let's try to be more explicit:

```
psql -h wrds-pgdata.wharton.upenn.edu –p 9737 -d myDatabase -U myAccountName -W
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "–p" ignored
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "9737" ignored
Password for user myAccountName:
```

No, that's not good either!
The only way I got this to work was:

```
PGPORT=9737; export PGPORT
psql -h wrds-pgdata.wharton.upenn.edu -d myDatabase -U myAccountName -W
```

I'm using psql (PostgreSQL) 9.5.8. Any idea's why the normal command line doesn't work?

Comment: I've got exactly the same problem as you. Whatever I do, the port argument is completely ignored. Did you ever find a solution ?

Comment: @BlueMagma No I did not. The only way I was able to work around this was to export the port number to the PGPORT variable as stated above: PGPORT=9737; export PGPORT

Answer (score 1):

That specific error is odd... but the following works for me. The last argument "wrds" is the name of the database where wrds stores everything.

```
psql -h wrds-pgdata.wharton.upenn.edu –p 9737 -U myUserBame -W wrds
```

Answer (score 0):

That is most odd. I've used `psql` in this way many times before and had it work. And your command seems fine from reading `man psql`. My version is also 9.5.8 but I don't have the exact set of circumstances to test.

The only thing I can suspect is that part of the domain is being interpreted as an argument;

wrds`-p`gdata.wharton.upenn.edu

Could you try;

```
psql -h "wrds-pgdata.wharton.upenn.edu" –p 9737 -d myDatabase -U myAccountName -W
```

Also, the manual notes that `--port=9737` is an alternate for just `-p`. You might have more luck with that.